# shopping card values in localstorage (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple shopping card store in jQuery. I am trying to make sure that after refresh my webapp, the data in the basket remains (if the data was added to the basket). I am trying to use localstorage, but I can not understand why it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("body").on("click", ".addtobasket", function (evt) {

        $("#kontener_koszyka").fadeIn();

        var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
        var cena = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.cenaprzedmiotu').text();

        var suma = 0;

        var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>"+nazwa+"</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>"+cena+" zł</span><span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

        localStorage.setItem('itemlist', li);

        $("#koszyk").append(li);

        $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function()
        {
            suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
        });
        $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
        localStorage.setItem('sumalist', suma);
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem('itemlist') != null)
    {
        $("#koszyk").append(itemlist);
        $("#cena span").text(sumalist.toFixed(2));
    }

    $(document).on('click','.deleteitembasket', function () {
        $(this).closest("li").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#koszyk").append(localStorage.getItem('itemlist'));`

Comment: There are multiple issues, the add should append values to the localstorage, in the same way delete should remove it

Comment: please create same problem in plunkr or stackblitz and post here. so we can solve your problem.

Comment: As @ArunPJohny said, you're only deleting the `li` on the page, but not in localStorage, save HTML objects instead and give them ID's. Add your code to [**`JSFiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: This is work, but this save only last item in my shopping card.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('itemlist', (localStorage.getItem('itemlist') || '') + li);`